# Unable to click on Next button after checking the checkbox

Tags: playwright, playwright-test, playwright-java

I have a checkbox and next button below it.

```
private String CHECKBOX = "[data-testid='checkbox_with_label']";
private String NEXT_BTN = "//button[@data-testid=\"next-button\"]/div";
```

I am checking the checkbox and then clicking on the *Next* button, but it just checks the checkbox and the program stops. I think it is not finding the *Next* button.

Below is the implementation:-

```
@Step("Select Termination checkbox information")
    public void selectCheckBox() {
        page.locator(CHECKBOX).evaluate("CHECKBOX => CHECKBOX.checked = true");   
    }

 @Step("Click next button")
    public void next() {
        page.locator(NEXT_BTN).click();
    }
```

I am not sure if my Xpaths are incorrect , please let me know how can I create proper Xpaths if that's the case.
The Xpath I get from browser is this - `//*[@id="page-wrap"]/main/div/div/div[17]/div/div/div[2]/button`

[image]

I have tried multiple Xpaths for *Next* button , but seems not one is working

```
 //private String NEXT_BTN = "[data-testid='next-button']";
 //private String NEXT_BTN = "next-button";   
 //*[@id="page-wrap"]/main/div/div/div[17]/div/div/div[2]/button
 //private String NEXT_BTN = "//*[@id=\"page-wrap\"]/main/div/div/div[17]/div/div/div[2]/button";
```

Comment: Please share the relevant html source .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a chrome extension that you can use to get the exact xpath of an element. You can refer here [Selectorsub](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/selectorshub/ndgimibanhlabgdgjcpbbndiehljcpfh)

I think you have not provided enough source code. It will be difficult for people to give you exact support.

P/S: In your code, for simplicity and clarity, you can use `page.locator(CHECKBOX).setChecked(true);` to tick the checkbox.
Click [here](https://playwright.dev/java/docs/api/class-locator#locator-set-checked) to refer method`setChecked`.

Answer (score 0):

Playwright provides a method `getByTestId()` to locate an element based on its `data-testid` attribute. You can check [this](https://playwright.dev/java/docs/locators#locate-by-test-id) section of the documentation to know more about this method.

So, can you please check whether the following code works for you?

```java
page.getByTestId("next-button").click();
```